# How to add esapi to ColdFusion 8

Tags: security, java, coldfusion

On https://github.com/damonmiller/esapi4cf there is a description of how to add the esapi jars to ColdFusion 9, but I'd like to know how to add them to ColdFusion 8.

I but the esapi-2.0.1.jar in a few of the Java Class Paths that are listed in the ColdFusion 8 admin's 'Settings Summary' but that does not seem to be helping, unless I need to restart the service which would suck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to restart the CF server for it to register any new JARs in the class paths. Otherwise you can use the [JavaLoader from Mark Mandel](http://javaloader.riaforge.org/) to load them dynamically.